# Animated GIF in Windows Form while executing long process

Tags: c#, picturebox, animated-gif

I have developed a simple windows Application(MDI) in C# which exports the data from SQL to Excel.

I am using ClosedXML to achieve this successfully.

When the process is executed, I want to show a picturebox containing a animated GIF image.

I am a beginner and don't know how to achieve this, the picturebox appears after the process is completed.

I saw lot of posts which says to use backgroundworker or threading which I have never used and finding it hard to implement.

Can I have an step by step example with explanation.

The two functions which I have created which I call before and after I execute the code.

```
        private void Loading_On()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
        groupBox1.Enabled = false;
        groupBox5.Enabled = false;
        groupBox6.Enabled = false;
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Arrow;
    }


    private void Loading_Off()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Arrow;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        groupBox1.Enabled = true;
        groupBox5.Enabled = true;
        groupBox6.Enabled = true;
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    }
```

Comment: I have used Thread to successfully show the Picture box but the groupbox are not disabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not that hard to add a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

- Open your form in the designer
- Open the Toolbox (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)
- Open the category Components
- Drag the Backgroundworker on your From

You will end-up with something like this:

> [image: winform with backgroundworker]

You can now switch to the event view on the Properties tab and add the events for [DoWork](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork(v=vs.110).aspx) and [RunWorkerCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)

> [image: event properties]

The following code goes in these events, notice how `DoWork` use the `DowWorkEventArgs` Argument property to retrieve the value that is supplied in `RunWorkerAsync`.

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // start doing what ever needs to be done
        // get the argument from the EventArgs
        string comboboxValue = (string) e.Argument; // if Argument isn't string, this breaks
        // remember that this is NOT on the UI thread

        // do a lot of work here that takes forever
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        // afer this the completed event is fired
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this runs on the UI thread
        Loading_Off();
    }
```

Now you only need to start the background job, for example from a button click event to call [`RunWorkerAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Loading_On();
         backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(comboBox1.SelectedItem); // pass a string here
    }
```

Done! You have successfully added a backgroundworker to your form.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that is running the animation in a async task, but accordingly some limitations is it possible to do that on windows forms using a Thread Sleep.

eg: In your constructor,

```
public partial class MainMenu : Form
{

    private SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();

    public MainMenu ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            splash.ShowDialog();
        });

       Thread.Sleep(2000);
   }
```

It is very important to put the Thread Sleep after have started a new one, don't forget that every action you did on this thread you need ot invoke, for example

```
    void CloseSplash(EventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
           splash.Close();
        }));
    }
```

Now your gif should work!