# gif stops working when other method is running c#

Tags: c#, animated-gif

I have a GIF Loading Icon I am trying to use when the login button of my form has been pressed. The problem I am having is that when the login button is clicked and the method that deals with the login is running the GIF stops working. I am trying to do this in a windows form using c#

I have tried using a background work similar to how this one was done
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33885/Working-with-BackgroundWorker-Creating-Your-Own-Lo

but it won't allow my code to access code from another thread any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You're probably running the login function on the same thread as the UI, so the UI blocks. Instead of running the UI on the background(animating the gif using a backgroundworker) run the login function.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your example link :

```
public void Start()   
{   
    Bw.RunWorkerAsync(); *// this is Async task*
    newLoading = new LoadingForm();   
    newLoading.ShowDialog();   
}
```

*Async task will run separatly from the main thread, so it doesn't affect loading of GIF which runs in the main thread.*

Here is a an answer to similar topic : [Animated GIF in Windows Form while executing long process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338288/animated-gif-in-windows-form-while-executing-long-process)

Comment: Thank you i did try this but i was having problems as the login method needs access to controls that was created by the main thread. I also tried switching it round and opening a panel using the new thread but with the same response