# Windows form show hide control not working as expacted

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have my code and problem like below

```
step1.Visible = true; 
//step1 is visible if i retrun from here but if do some work like below than its not visible until the task is completed
Thread.Sleep(5000); // some opration here  Thread.Sleep is just for example
step1.Visible = true;// step1 visible here not before thread going to sleep
```

Here I want to show the image for each step but first step image not showing if it's followed by some long running task any idea/trick show step1 in the case of Thread.Sleep(5000)?

Comment: you should use delegate to achieve that. It's now possible in that way.

Comment: @AbhishekK.Upadhyay can i have some sample code for this

Comment: Because you're blocking the thread (sleeping) then nothing will be updated. More than that UI will _hung_ and become unresponsive. Use task(s) to chain actions dispatching changes back to UI thread. Plenty of examples of this, check for Control.BeginInvoke

Comment: @jitender - Don't ever use Application.DoEvents(). It's only in the framework for backward compatibility with VB6. It will cause hard-to-resolve bugs with your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks any other suggestion should I use background worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Application.DoEvents()` before your Sleep (Any long running) Code.
Application.DoEvents() will processes all Windows messages currently in the message queue.

```
step1.Visible = true; 

// Below 3 lines are not necessary. Use it only if DoEvents() doesn't work.
//step1.Invalidate();
//step1.Update();
//step1.Refresh();

// Will process the pending request of step1.Visible=true;
Application.DoEvents();

Thread.Sleep(5000);
step1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: @haeeb thanks, this is much simpler and working fine

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` is just a dirty workaround for a broken design, please do not suggest to use it in production code. Also: sleeping in the UI thread will hang UI, definitely something we do not want to happen. In short: no, this isn't the way to go to solve your problem (even if it _seems_ simple).

Comment: No, no, no! Don't ever use `Application.DoEvents()`. It's only in the framework for backward compatibility with VB6. It will cause hard-to-resolve bugs with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what do you want to do but first I will use those two function : [Show()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Hide()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide(v=vs.110).aspx)

Now you have to work with [Multi Threading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178(v=vs.90).aspx) and comunication between Threads

Hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegates or backgroundworker process to achieve that. you can get and idea from the link below.

[Animated GIF in Windows Form while executing long process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338288/animated-gif-in-windows-form-while-executing-long-process)

Thanks

Comment: Link-only answers are less valuable then they might be. **This** is the way to go but please insert a few lines code snippet and another few lines to explain why attempted approach doesn't work as expected! You'll definitely have my +1 then!